# Interesting tab

Tags: feature-request

StackOverflow has an [interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting), showing unanswered questions it expects you'll be able to answer. This is very useful.

Please can it be added to SF?

Comment: New features are commonly tested on SO, they're distributed to the other sites once they're vetted.

Answer (score 3):

The interesting tab was designed to solve problems for busy sites like StackOverflow. There are no other sites sufficiently busy that they require it.

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69836/the-interesting-tab-on-other-sites)